# Java gson replace member object when serialized

Tags: java, gson, android

I'm trying to design a flatter structure for the output JSON file. How do I make it so that when I use `gson.toJson()` the member object will be serialized using the object's ID instead of serializing the whole thing?

For example:

```
class Foo {
    public int id;
}

class Bar {
    public Foo foo = new Foo();
    public String data = "something";
}
```

I want `gson.toJson(bar)` to output something like this: `{"foo": 1029, "data":"something"}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
public class FooBarAdapter implements JsonSerializer<Bar> {

   @Override
   public JsonElement serialize(Bar bar, Type typeOfObj,
        JsonSerializationContext context)
   {

       JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
       obj.addProperty("foo", bar.foo.id);
       obj.addProperty("data", bar.data);

       return obj;
   }

}
```

and then when you want to serialize it:

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Bar.class, new FooBarAdapter());
return gsonBuilder.create().toJson(bar);
```

Comment: what do you mean exactly? this code should output what you wanted

Comment: Sorry, I meant deserializing. I've figured it out by using `JsonDeserializer<Bar>`.